# Manipulate a number algorithm

Tags: python

How can I fix this algo?

```
def change_num(n, direc, numMove):
    if direc == 'back':
        nums = range(10)
        return nums[n-numMove]
    elif direc == 'forward':
        nums = range(10)
        nums.reverse()
        return nums[n-numMove]-1
```

This doesn't work for direc == 'back'
here are some sample expected returns:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

change_num(1,'back', 5)  -> 6
change_num(5,'back', 1)  -> 4
change_num(7,'forward',5) -> 2
change_num(0,'forward',5) -> 5
```

Do you understand how the algo works? I'm just not implementing it right.

Comment: Why `change_num(7,'forward',5) -> 4`?

Comment: ya it was typo, should be '2', fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `'back'` and `'forward'`, it will be easier to pass `+1` for forward and `-1` for back.  Then your function simplifies to

```
def change_num(n, direc, num_move):
    return (n + direc * num_move) % 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def change_num(n, direc, numMove):
   d = {'back' : -1, 'forward' : 1}
   return (n + d[direc]*numMove) % 10
```

Have you given thought to what this function does?  this `num` list is pointless bc `num[x]` === `x`.  You don't need if statements for 'back' and 'forward', they really just correspond to `-1` and `1` respectively.

Comment: I take it nums is defined as nums = range(10)

Comment: there is no nums.  i mistyped before

Answer (score 0):

Your function is over-complicated and won't work in Python 3.

```
% cat ./test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest

def change_num(n, direc, numMove):
    directions = {
            'back': -1,
            'forward': +1,
            }
    steps = n + directions[direc] * numMove
    wrapped = steps % 10
    return wrapped

class TestChangeNum(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_back_no_wrap(self):
        self.assertEquals(6, change_num(1, 'back', 5))

    def test_back_with_wrap(self):
        self.assertEquals(4, change_num(5, 'back', 1))

    def test_forward_with_wrap(self):
        self.assertEquals(2, change_num(7, 'forward', 5))

    def test_forward_no_wrap(self):
        self.assertEquals(5, change_num(0, 'forward', 5))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

% python test.py 
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK
```